# How can I quickly change display settings from dual monitor to single monitor on laptop?

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, external-display, display-settings

I have my laptop (running Windows XP SP3) at work hooked up to an external monitor. 
Whenever I unplug the external monitor (time to go home!) I have to manually change the display settings. This takes time and involves a lot of clicks.

Is there a way to automate changing these settings? I'm thinking of a hotkey solution or a little application that I can start with Launchy to toggle between two profiles.

I use the [MultiMon](http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm) tool for "extending" the taskbar to the second monitor - will I have to give that up?

Comment: What kind of laptop do you have?  I believe Lenovo Thinkpads have custom software for toggling displays.  It's not automated, but involves fewer clicks.

Comment: Most laptops have a hotkey or function key combination for toggling display modes.

Comment: I'm running Windows XP on a 2007 MacBook Pro... (the function key does not do much)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently trying out [MurGeeMon](http://www.murgee.com/MurGeeMon/) - it only costs $5 and lets you disable the external monitor via a shortcut or via a tray icon menu. I think I will buy.

Comment: I would say UltraMon is probably much, much better.  UltraMon FTW!

Answer (score 1):

This was just posted on Lifehacker.com today:

[HRC – HotKey Resolution Changer](http://www.funk.eu/hrc/)

Comment: the documentation indicates only resultion changing - and also specifically says it won't work with different resolutions per monitor :(

Comment: @daren your question only seems to ask about resolution changing/toggling with hotkeying.

Answer (score 1):

[UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) has support for [display profiles](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/display_profiles.asp) which can be activated via shortcuts

It also has a [Smart Taskbar](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/smart_taskbar.asp) which provides a start bar on all monitors.